# Как сделать обратную сортировку по клику JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который сортирует таблицу, по нажатию на кнопку необходимо чтобы сортировка была обратной, как это можно сделать?

```js
  $(function () {
      var a_sort = $('#sorting span');
      var div_conteiner = jQuery.makeArray($('#conteiner div'));
      a_sort.each(function (index, self) {
             var id = $(self).parent().attr("id");
             $(self).click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  div_conteiner.sort(function f(a, b) {
                      a = $(a).data(id);
                      b = $(b).data(id);
                      var c = 0
                      if (a > b) c = 1;
                      if (a < b) c = -1;
                      return c
                   });
                   if (index%2) div_conteiner.reverse()
                   $.map(div_conteiner, function (div) {
                      $(div).appendTo($('#conteiner'))
                   });
               });
        });
});
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div id="sorting">
            <a href="#" id="price"><span>цена &#9650;</span></a>
            <a href="#" id="name"><span>название &#9650;</span></a>
            <a href="#" id="rating"><span>рейтинг &#9650;</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="conteiner">
            <div data-price="200" data-name="b" data-rating="4">Text 2 price_200 name_b rating_4</div>
            <div data-price="100" data-name="c" data-rating="5">Text 1 price_100 name_c rating_5</div>
            <div data-price="300" data-name="a" data-rating="3">Text 3 price_300 name_a rating_3</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто добавить обратную настройку к методу [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), который Вы уже и так используете:

```
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
console.log(numbers) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
console.log(numbers) // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```